# Strange Javascript for loop behavior when using Jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm probably missing/doing something silly, but I can't seem to work this out:

Here's a fiddle showing the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/jhqjmcn4/1/

Note that you will need to open your console to see what is happening.

Basically, in this example, I have two functions containing a for loop that are identical to each other except the second one contains a JQuery append.

The goal of the function is to get the html elements from within a string, which works fine in the first function, but not the second.

As can be seen in the console, this causes anything that is not a text node to be ignored and not added to the list. In this case, the b and p tags are not being included.

Here is the code again:

JS:

```
function parse_text(text) {
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.innerHTML = text;
    var elements = div.childNodes;
    var container = jQuery("#container");
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        var element = elements[i];
        list.push(element);
        console.log("First", list);
    }
}

function parse_text_two(text) {
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.innerHTML = text;
    var elements = div.childNodes;
    var container = jQuery("#container2");
    var list = [];
    for (var p = 0; p < elements.length; p++){
        var element = elements[p];
        list.push(element);
        console.log("Second", list);
        container.append(element);
    }
}

var text = "Here is <b>some</b> text with <p>html</p> in it";

parse_text(text);
parse_text_two(text);
```

html (irrelevant):

```
<div id="container">

</div>
<div id="container2">

</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the objective?

Comment: Both the Methods are working fine... What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: The problem is in the second function when application runs element.length contains 5 but for each iteration this length is getting changed and element.length is becoming 3. This is because of container.append function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to have a `Array.prototype.filter()` method to get the html elements:

```js
function parse_text_two(text) {
  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
  div.innerHTML = text;
  var elements = [].filter.call(div.childNodes, function(el) {
    return el.nodeType !== 3;
  });
  var container = jQuery("#container2");

  var list = [];
  for (var p = 0; p < elements.length; p++) {
    var element = elements[p];
    list.push(element);
    console.log("Second", list);
    container.append(element);
  }
}

var text = "Here is <b>some</b> text with <p>html</p> in it";


parse_text_two(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
<div id="container2">
</div>
```

Comment: Would you please explain to me why this makes any difference compared to the way I was doing it?

Comment: Because that was a collection, an array like object but not actual array, if you log `elements` with your previous code, you can see there will something else otherthan child nodes too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check updated fiddle here [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/jhqjmcn4/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/jhqjmcn4/3/)

Its return same result for both methods in console as per you want.

```
function parse_text_two(text) {    
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.innerHTML = text;
    var elementsOrg = div.childNodes;
    var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elementsOrg);;
    var container = jQuery("#container2");
    var list = [];
    for (var p = 0; p < elements.length; p++){
        var element = elements[p];
        list.push(element);
        console.log("Second", list);
        container.append(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I saw by putting a debug point inside the loop was this:

The `container.append(element);` statement was actually modifying the elements array and was removing the appended element from the array. Which meant that in the loop for various values of 'p' the elements array looked like this:

```
p = 0 -> elements : [ text, b, text, p, text ] // text node at 0 picked
p = 1 -> elements : [ b, text, p, text ] // text node at 1 picked
p = 2 -> elements : [ text, p, text ] // text node at 2 picked
```

That is why the loop only ran 3 times instead of the original length of the elements array , i.e. 5.

This probably happens because jQuery 'moves' the node from its original place to the container div.

You can either clone the element node and then append into the container:

```
function parse_text_two(text) {
    var div = document.createElement("DIV"),
        p,
        element,
        elements,
        container = jQuery("#container2"),
        list = [];

    div.innerHTML = text;
    elements = div.childNodes;

    for (p = 0; p < elements.length; p++){
        element = elements[p];
        list.push(element);
        console.log("Second", list);
        container.append($(element).clone());
    }
}
```

Or use a while loop as suggested in Venkatesh's answer. Anyway, it is always better to know the root cause. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In second function in each loop comment this line container.append(element);